# Sentry grants applied but not ACL working until a database is specified

Tags: hive, hdfs, file-permissions, acl, apache-sentry

I configured a admin role in Sentry with the next permissions:

- server=server1->action=ALL

In Hive everything works: We can create objects, inserts, selects...

But the HDFS folders haven't the correct ACL:

```
 hdfs dfs -getfacl /user/hive/warehouse/testgrant
 # file: /user/hive/warehouse/testgrant
 # owner: hive
 # group: hive
 user::rwx
 group::---
 user:hive:rwx
 group:hive:rwx
 mask::rwx
 other::--x
```

But if I set the database or the table in Sentry with next config:

- server=server1  db=default  table=testgrant  action=ALL

Then I can see the correct ACL:

```
 # file: /user/hive/warehouse/testgrant
 # owner: hive
 # group: hive
 user::rwx
 group::---
 user:hive:rwx
 group:hive:rwx
 group:g_datalake_dba_des:rwx
 mask::rwx
 other::--x
```

This is a problem, because I want to have ACL access automatically when I create a table in Hive without define a specific permission in Sentry (I have ALL in Server)

How can I configure Sentry to do this?

Thanks!